# Disable the Account Lock-Out option - Bugzilla 4.2.1

Tags: bugzilla

My current bugzilla 4.2.1 installation blocks any user temporarily for
multiple login failures. If they try to use incorrect password for,
say 5 times, they will not be able to login again and a mail is being
sent to the maintainer of the installation. Is there anyway I can
disable the Account Lock-Out feature? I don't want any user to be
blocked due to login failures.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the directory where Bugzilla resides there is a file called Constants.pm edit the file and set the MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS value to 1000000.

-note: in my installation the file was in /var/www/bugzilla/Bugzilla/